# Proportionately position element over responsive image

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

We have a responsive image, and there are elements positioned absolutely above the image - The elements positioned above the image need to stay in the exact same position proportionate with the image.

For example: http://jsbin.com/juremuqa/1/edit - I want the red circles on the cat to stay above the eyes. The circles do not have to resize, just cover the eyes no matter height or width of square element. The image should also scale proportionately.

Possible in just CSS? Or would you have to calculate label position with JS?

The positioned elements will be text in the end.

Comment: The ratio is not maintained when displaying the image. Maintain the ratio of the image and your task is done.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the Css.

```
    .square .image {
     background: url('http://animalkingdomz00.com/images/chartreux-cat-6.jpg');
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     display: block;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

Try and tell me

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense, but I don't want to stretch the image: http://jsbin.com/qatoyala/2/edit

Comment: As in your code. You have given the red dots to be in percent position. Hence if that is fixed in px and also the image dimensions are fixed in px you can get the desired results.

Comment: ...But then it's not in any way responsive?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the red dots to do anything then the easiest solution is to replace the eyes with a transparent background and let the red background color shine through. Otherwise your going to need to play around with image positioning, right now your problem is that your keeping height and width both fixed which means when the image changes size it stretches in ways that change the height to width ratio making your eye percents fail. If you want that then SSS has the right idea.